# I want to display all users and their details but getting invalid foreach argument

Tags: php, foreach

i want to display all users and their details as a table from the wordpress database using foreach. But am getting an invalid foreach argument! 
What i have written is it correct ? what is the mistake in it ? 
please help me

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: User Page */
?>

<?php
get_header(); ?>

<?php

echo "<h2> List Of Members</h2>";
echo "<table class='table table bordered'>";
echo "<thead> 
      <tr>


      <th>Member Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Class</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      </tr>
      <thead>";

foreach ($row as $row) 

    {
    $usid = $row->ID;
    $username = $row->user_login;

    echo "<tr><td>".$username."</td>";
    $age=get_user_meta( $usid, 'age', true);
    echo "<td>".$age."</td>";
    $class=get_user_meta($usid, 'class', true);
    echo "<td>".$class."</td>";
    $address=get_user_meta($usid, 'address', true);
    echo "<td>".$address."</td>";
    }   
?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `$row as $row` since the values are overwritten there. So, you might use like `$rows as $row` or `$row as $data`

Comment: I tried the method yu suggested, but it didnt do any good. But thanks for the help though

Comment: Where have you defined `$row` for `foreach($row as $row)`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
foreach ($row as $row)
```

Try to understand the basic concept first, `foreach()` needs two parameter:

```
foreach ($dataArray as $var)
```

on each iteration `$var` gets the new index value from `$dataArray` into it and the loop iterate till its last index. So change it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Issue here is, same variable name is using for looping.

```
foreach ($row as $row)
```

Use different names for variables to avoid the overriding.
Also print the $row to confirm the result

```
print_r($row);// to verify the array
foreach ($row as $eachRow)
{
    $usid = $eachRow->ID;
    $username = $eachRow->user_login;
    ...
    ....
}
```